# Spring MVC helloworld - Package name cannot start with java?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, classnotfoundexception

Open Eclipse --> New Project --> Spring Project --> Spring MVC Project -->

After giving the name of project give the package name as 
**java**.example.com  ( where it shows com.myexample.myapp* )

When you will start the Tomcat Server you will see ClassNotFoundException as
then Spring MVC cannot read the Controller HelloController.

I m not able to figure out the root cause but if my package name doesn't start with java everything works fine.

Comment: Give your Controller package name in `Dispatcher-servlet.xml`, using this property `<context:component-scan base-package="com.myexample.myapp" />`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `java` package is **reserved** for Java runtime classes. For security reasons, you are not allowed to create your own classes with that name.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.1.

> Names of packages intended only for local use should have a first identifier that begins with a lowercase letter, but that first identifier specifically should **not be the identifier java**; package names that start with the identifier java are reserved for package of the Java SE platform.

Comment: The java language spec only mentions java as reserved, not javax. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.1

Comment: @JeroenK Thanks, man. `javax` removed and quoted java doc.  :-)